# php array_values() parameter error

Tags: magento2

What is the mistake in my parameter?

```
protected function _construct()
{
     $this->_init("sync/queue", "id");
}
```

My `sync/queue` ->
I get

> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php
>   on line 146

Comment: If i use $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue', 'id');                i get Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config.php on line 157

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused from Plug-in configuration from your custom Module, Not the _construct().

Assume you have used Plug-in and missed some method in your module.

Expected the breaking.

```
    $pluginMethod = 'around' . $capMethod;
    $result = $pluginInstance->$pluginMethod($this, $next, ...array_values($arguments));
    unset($pluginInstance, $pluginMethod);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please check this updated link of my answer @Krishna   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126624/magento-2-model-resource-and-collection-error-array-values-expects-parameter

Comment: There still im facing the same issue..